# rails s command no longer working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rbenv

I am new to Rails and programming in general.  I built an app by following a tutorial on YouTube.  I got the whole thing done, then started fiddling with Ruby and Rails versions.  Maybe a mistake....  Anyway, I can no longer get the Rails S command to work.  Pasted below is the error I am getting.  I welcome any suggestions you might have.

tom@linux:~/apps/BookReview$ rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.2.0 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Exiting
/home/tom/apps/BookReview/config/environments/development.rb:3:in `block in <top (required)>': uninitialized constant Paperclip (NameError)
    from /home/tom/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/railtie.rb:216:in`instance_eval'
    from /home/tom/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/railtie.rb:216:in `configure'
    from /home/tom/apps/BookReview/config/environments/development.rb:1:in`'
    from /home/tom/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:602:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
    from /home/tom/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:601:in`each'
    from /home/tom/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:601:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    from /home/tom/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in`instance_exec'
    from /home/tom/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
    from /home/tom/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in`block in run_initializers'
    from /home/tom/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /home/tom/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in`block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/tom/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:422:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /home/tom/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in`each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /home/tom/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:421:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /home/tom/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in`each'
    from /home/tom/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `tsort_each_child'
    from /home/tom/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:415:in`call'
    from /home/tom/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:415:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /home/tom/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:349:in`block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/tom/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    from /home/tom/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in`call'
    from /home/tom/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/tom/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:226:in`tsort_each'
    from /home/tom/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    from /home/tom/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in`run_initializers'
    from /home/tom/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in `initialize!'
    from /home/tom/apps/BookReview/config/environment.rb:5:in`'
    from config.ru:3:in `require_relative'
    from config.ru:3:in`block in '
    from /home/tom/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from /home/tom/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in`initialize'
    from config.ru:in `new'
    from config.ru:in`'
    from /home/tom/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    from /home/tom/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in`new_from_string'
    from /home/tom/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /home/tom/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/server.rb:319:in`build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from /home/tom/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/server.rb:219:in `app'
    from /home/tom/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:27:in`app'
    from /home/tom/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/server.rb:354:in `wrapped_app'
    from /home/tom/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:89:in`log_to_stdout'
    from /home/tom/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:51:in `start'
    from /home/tom/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:147:in`block in perform'
    from /home/tom/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `tap'
    from /home/tom/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in`perform'
    from /home/tom/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /home/tom/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in`invoke_command'
    from /home/tom/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
    from /home/tom/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in`perform'
    from /home/tom/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
    from /home/tom/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in`'
    from /home/tom/apps/BookReview/bin/rails:9:in `require'
    from /home/tom/apps/BookReview/bin/rails:9:in`'
    from /home/tom/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    from /home/tom/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in`call'
    from /home/tom/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /home/tom/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in`run'
    from /home/tom/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/tom/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in`load'
    from /home/tom/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/tom/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in`require'
    from /home/tom/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
    from /home/tom/apps/BookReview/bin/spring:15:in`'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in`'

Comment: Did you `bundle install` after adding Paperclip to your `Gemfile`?

Comment: Also recommend looking into `ActiveStorage` instead of Paperclip if you are on Rails 5.2+, as Paperclip is deprecated: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/closing-the-trombone

Comment: I somehow lost Paperclip along the way.  That was the problem.  I will look into ActiveStorage for sure.  Thanks for that tip.

Answer (score 0):

Include the paperclip gem in your Gemfile, if it's not already added.

```
gem "paperclip", git: "git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git"
```

After that run `bundle install`